# Ruby functional programming confusion -- (Beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know I'm looping twice in the following code for no reason. How could I go the following loop of records in one step instead of first selecting them and then performing actions on it.

```
merchants = Merchant.all.select do |merchant|
  merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.new_data.url
end

merchants.each do |merchant|
  merchant.url = merchant.new_data.url
  merchant.save!
end
```

I bet it's something very simple -- I'm new to Ruby so all this is new to me.

Comment: Does `merchant.save!` save even when no attributes have been modified?

Comment: No, I'd only like to update it if the new data is different (hence the first select to only get those records.

Comment: Why? For performance reasons?

Comment: Yes. Since the tables have millions of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's conceptually ok to iterate over data on separate steps (this allows modularization and composability). Granted, this may be a bit inefficient when using strict structures (as opposed to lazy ones) like Ruby arrays, but no worries for small/medium arrays. Anyway, of course you can join the logic in one step, like this:

```
Merchant.all.each do |merchant|
  if merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.new_data.url
    merchant.url = merchant.new_data.url
    merchant.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution iterate over all merchants?

Comment: @Mark. Yeah, I just translated the code in the question. If I had thousand of merchants I'd use find_each for example. In another question I already advised the OP to use scopes instead of Ruby loops but I guess he finds it easier to do it in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

It will be quite inefficient doing `Merchant.all` when you have millions of rows, especially if they have many large fields. I would move the selection logic into the ActiveRecord query, something like this (untested):

```
Merchant.includes(:new_data).select(:url).where("url IS NOT NULL").where("url != new_data.url")
```

Comment: Doesn't `Merchant.all.select` build a similar query? Or does it get the entire table and then loop to remove non-matching items from a hash?

Comment: Hmm... it might. Certainly `Merchant.all.each` will not. Do you even need the `all`?

Comment: +1. I would create scopes in Merchant to reuse the code, but that's in fact the good way to do it, filtering at SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for nil merchant url

```
merchants.each do |merchant|
  merchant.url = merchant.url || merchant.new_data.url
  merchant.save!
end
```